# hide nib content until completion of a task

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nib

I am trying to complete a task, and then want the xib content to be shown on the view. However the VC is being initialized via nibFile, is there a way to do lazy loading of nib once the task is completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.view.hidden = YES;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do your background tasks here
    [self doSomethingInBackground];

    // when that method finishes you can run whatever you need to on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.view.hidden = NO;
    });
});
```

(adapted from [Implement a block in background, then after completion run another block on main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588412/implement-a-block-in-background-then-after-completion-run-another-block-on-main))

Answer (score 0):

Put the task in a background thread, when this finish refresh the main thread to load the nib.

Remember, the view in iOS application run in Main thread, if you are doing a task and this no finish quickly, the best way is run the task in background.